# Using -fsanitize=address g++

Tags: g++, runtime, compiler-warnings, memory-address

```
Compiler: gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4) (GCC)
OS : CentOS
```

I have the following code:

```
void
foo24()
{
    int x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int
main()
{
    foo24();
    return 0;
}
```

If `-Wall`  is turned on there is a warning for un-initialized memory.

When I run my executable compiler with `-fsanitize=address`, I do not get any such warnings or errors.

Any idea why? Is it supposed to deal with only specific kind of errors.

Answer (score 0):

AddressSanitizer (enabled with `-fsanitize-address`) checks for buffer overflows, not for uninitialized memory. For the latter you should use [MemorySanitizer](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/MemorySanitizer.html) (only available in Clang, enabled with `-fsanitize=memory`) or Valgrind.